# Overwrite null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
var newThing = db.Things.SingleOrDefault(t => t.ThingName == viewModel.ThingName);

if (newThing == null)
{
    newThing.ThingName.Equals(viewModel.ThingName);
}
```

Where the above if statement is true, I'm receiving an

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

exception because newThing is null. Is it possible to initialise NewThing and set newThing.ThingName to viewModel.ThingName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize it ans set its value

```
if (newThing == null)
{
    newThing = new Thing(); 
    newThing.ThingName = viewModel.ThingName;
}
```

Comment: An important note is that this of course won't add the new thing to the DB. It's not clear from the question if that's desired or not.

Comment: @svick, You are absolutely rigth

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Satpals solution, here is a one-liner to get the item from DataBase or initialize a new one:

```
var newThing = db.Things.SingleOrDefault
    (t => t.ThingName == viewModel.ThingName) ??
    new Thing { ThingName = viewModel.ThingName };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you would need to create a new instance of `Thing` first.

Snippet:

```
if (newThing == null)
{
    newThing = new Thing();
    newThing.ThingName = viewModel.ThingName; //Set the ThingName to what is wanted.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Satpal, you too quick for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused.

```
something.Equals(somethingElse);
```

returns `true or false` whether `something` and `somethingElse` are equal.

```
something = somethingElse;
```

sets `something` to `somethingElse`. *This is what you want to do.*

Additionally:

```
something == somethingElse
```

returns `true or false` whether `something` and `somethingElse` are equal.

Comment: Now I got confused ;)